# Why this function isn't called in this scenario

Tags: reactjs

I learn React.js and JavaScript and now I have this problem that this below `{WithFetching(XlsxVie...` `function` is never called.
The `WithFetching` should be called with `XlsxViewer` and `newProps` as arguments but I missed something don't know because it's not working:

```
import WithFetching from '../file-viewer/fetch-wrapper';

    const newProps = { ...this.props, responseType: 'arraybuffer', fileType: 'xlsx', filePath: { theFile } };
    return (
        <div className="pg-viewer-wrapper">
            <div className="pg-viewer" id="pg-viewer">
                {WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)};
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
```

And this is the `WithFetching`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Error from './error';
import Loading from './loading';

function WithFetching(WrappedComponent, props) {
    return class FetchComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            // eslint-disable-line no-shadow
            super(props);
            this.state = {};
            this.xhr = this.createRequest(props.filePath);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            try {
                this.fetch();
            } catch (e) {
                if (this.props.onError) {
                    this.props.onError(e);
                }
                this.setState({ error: 'fetch error' });
            }
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.abort();
        }

        createRequest(path) {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
                // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
                xhr.open('GET', path, true);
            // } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== 'undefined') {
            //  // XDomainRequest for IE.
            //  xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            //  xhr.open('GET', path);
            } else {
                // CORS not supported.
                xhr = null;
                return null;
            }
            if (props.responseType) {
                xhr.responseType = props.responseType;
            }

            xhr.onload = () => {
                if (xhr.status >= 400) {
                    this.setState({ error: `fetch error with status ${xhr.status}` });
                    return;
                }
                const resp = props.responseType ? xhr.response : xhr.responseText;

                this.setState({ data: resp });
            };

            return xhr;
        }

        fetch() {
            this.xhr.send();
        }

        abort() {
            if (this.xhr) {
                this.xhr.abort();
            }
        }

        render() {
            if (!this.xhr) {
                return <h1>CORS not supported..</h1>;
            }

            if (this.state.error) {
                return <Error {...this.props} error={this.state.error} />;
            }

            if (this.state.data) {
                return <WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
            }
            return <Loading />;
        }
    };
}

export default WithFetching;
```

This is the `XlxsViewer`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

import CsvViewer from './csv-viewer';

class XlxsViewer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.parse();
    }

    parse() {
        const dataArr = new Uint8Array(this.props.data);
        const arr = [];

        for (let i = 0; i !== dataArr.length; i += 1) {
            arr.push(String.fromCharCode(dataArr[i]));
        }

        const workbook = XLSX.read(arr.join(''), { type: 'binary' });
        const names = Object.keys(workbook.Sheets);
        const sheets = names.map(name => XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[name]));

        return { sheets, names, curSheetIndex: 0 };
    }

    renderSheetNames(names) {
        const sheets = names.map((name, index) => (
            <input
                key={name}
                type="button"
                value={name}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ curSheetIndex: index });
                }}
            />
        ));

        return <div className="sheet-names">{sheets}</div>;
    }

    renderSheetData(sheet) {
        const csvProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, { data: sheet });
        return <CsvViewer {...csvProps} />;
    }

    render() {
        const { sheets, names, curSheetIndex } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="spreadsheet-viewer">
                {this.renderSheetNames(names)}
                {this.renderSheetData(sheets[curSheetIndex || 0])}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default XlxsViewer;
```

Why is not the `WithFetching` called?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is intended or not, but you trying to render a `class` instead of an instance of that class. Maybe you can save the return value of your call to `WithFetching` in a variable and then instantiate an object of that class?

Comment: Thanks @ NiklasMohrin I'm new to Reactjs (newbie) can you elaborate this better as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)
```

Change it to:

```
<XlsxViewer newProps={newProps} />
```

and in XlxsViewer.js, change

```
export default XlxsViewer;
```

with:

```
export default WithFetching(XlxsViewer);
```

In WithFetching.js, change

```
function WithFetching(WrappedComponent, props) {
```

with:

```
function WithFetching(WrappedComponent) {
```

and the newProps are accessed as this.props within FetchComponent

Comment: Thanks I will test this...give me a sec or  a day

Comment: Your a genius thanks I think it can work as you say!. Running some more tests now will accept this probably nice explanation.  I [stumbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843352/from-reactjs-xmlhttprequest-loading-an-xlsx-file-show-strange-output) on a new problem the XLSX file is not loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

`WithFecthing` is returning a class, not an instance of a class.

So instead of calling

```js
WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)
```

You would have to call

```js
new WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)
```

Mind you that using it this way, the component will be recreated every time the parent component gets called.
It would be better to create a component called `FetchingXlsxViewer` that just exports the `WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)` as a default.

Comment: I tried this like ´div className="pg-viewer" id="pg-viewer">
       {new WithFetching(XlsxViewer, newProps)};
      </div>´ But no breakpoints are hit in `WithFetching` There is not change in my problem!¨